# is this ffmpeg command optimized?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a requirement to take a video, add some plain text, and then add some rotated text at different times, locations, and durations.  I want to use processor power in the most efficient way this will run 20,000 times (yes, really, we're personalizing a video for students at a U.)This is what I finally came up with:

```
ffmpeg -y -i INPUT.mp4 -filter_complex 
  "drawtext=enable='between(t,14,16)':fontfile=tahoma.ttf:fontsize=54:fontcolor=green:x=10:y=text_h + 10:text='Dana Scully',
   drawtext=enable='between(t,19,23)':fontfile=tahoma.ttf:fontsize=16:fontcolor=red:x=150:y=220:text='Dana Scully  \<Dana.Scully\@fbi.gov\>',
   drawtext=enable='between(t,99,104)':fontfile=tahoma.ttf:fontsize=28:fontcolor=green:x=480:y=text_h + 160:text='Dana Scully',
   drawtext=enable='between(t,14,16)':fontfile=tahoma.ttf:fontsize=16:fontcolor=yellow:x=40:y=25:text='Dana Scully  \<Dana.Scully\@fbi.gov\>',
   drawtext=enable='between(t,180,186)':fontfile=tahoma.ttf:fontsize=88:fontcolor=green:x=20:y=430:text='Dana Scully'[text];
   color=c=#111111:s=1280x720:d=1,format=yuv444p[colorbk];
   [colorbk]drawtext=fontfile=tahoma.ttf:fontsize=16:fontcolor=purple:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2:text='by',drawtext=fontfile=tahoma.ttf:fontsize=32:fontcolor=green:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=((h-text_h)/2)+50:text='Dana Scully',rotate=(-.5):ow=1280:oh=720:c=#111111,chromakey=#111111:similarity=0.01,format=yuva444p,colorkey=#111111:0.1[rotated];
   [text][rotated]overlay=eval=frame:x='if(gte(t,134),(if(lte(t,137),20,NAN)), NAN)':y=100[out];[out]scale=iw*.25:-1" 
   -crf 20 test.mp4
```

Is that about as optimized as it is going to get?  I thought ffmpeg would already handle the threads based on the computer's processor, so no real need to mess with it.  The processing will all be done on AWS VMs.

Rotating the text is what really slows it down.

Any ideas?

Comment: I can offer more suggestions tomorrow, but use a transparent canvas and skip the chroma/colorkeys. Also, use enable for overlay and skip per-frame eval.

Comment: @Mulvya - I didn't use your example exactly, but you put me on the right track.  I don't know why I didn't think of it before.  Probably because I'm still learning ffmpeg and didn't know as much a week ago. :)

I created a 1280x720 png file that was just a blank transparency.  So instead of creating a canvas, I just loaded the png, wrote on it, then rotated the output.  Since I never save the png, I can reuse it.  I think I went from 1400 seconds to < 300 seconds, almost 20 minutes off the time.

Comment: ffmpeg -y -i INPUT.mp4 -i transparent.png -filter_complex 
      "drawtext=enable='between(t,14,16)':fontfile=tahoma.ttf:fontsize=54:fontcolor=green:x=10:y=text_h + 10:text='Dana Scully',
       drawtext=enable=<SNIP>:text='Dana Scully'[text];
       [1:v]drawtext=fontfile=tahoma.ttf:fontsize=16:fontcolor=purple:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2:text='by',<SNIP>
       [finalfive];
       [text][finalfive]overlay=enable:x='if(gte(t,134),(if(lte(t,137),20,NAN)), NAN)':y=100[out];[out]scale=iw*.25:-1" -crf 20 test.mp4